# Swift Error while updating a simple mutable Dictionary

Tags: swift

I have a very simple Swift code:

```
var dictionary = ["cat" : 2, "dog" : 4, "snake" : 8]
dictionary["lion"] = 7
dictionary += ["bear" : 1, "mouse" : 6]
```

Swift compiler complains with this:

play12.swift:69:1: error: '[String : Int]' is not identical to 'UInt8'
dictionary += ["bear" : 1, "mouse" : 6]

What am I missing??

Anand

Comment: I think you can try removing the '+' sign in the 3rd line and it should work fine.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf I'm not familiar with `swift`, but I'm pretty sure that would redefine dictionary instead of append to it?

Comment: @Al.Sal neither am I familiar, but, using the logic of one by one defining, I think it should work.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf I'm not so sure. In any other language, a code snippet like `x = 5` followed by `x = 6` will discard 5. Same thing here.

Comment: @Al.Sal is he using the wrong operator then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to update a dictionary using an operator, nor do I think there will be. When you think about the differences between arrays and hashtables, being able to append to an array makes sense because arrays are cumulative and sequential.

The expression: `myArray += value` is intuitive. You can look at is as saying "I'm incrementing this array's index by adding these values". It also doesn't conflict with previous additions since each new addition is given a unique index.

`myDict += [key : value]` is less intuitive, some unintentional things can occur. For instance, What do we do if that key already exists?  What if the key is unique but the hashValue exists? The operation's no longer clearly just "append this item to my collection" it's now become "Attempt to append this item and figure out any conflicts on your own".

So long story short, if you want that functionality you're going to have implement it yourself, this should give you the functionality you want. Keep in mind any conflicting keys will be overwritten

```
@infix func += <T:Hashable, U:Any>(inout lhs:[T:U], rhs:[T:U]){
    for (key,value) in rhs{
        lhs[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Although, the error message could be somewhat less cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

apples example of adding to a dictionary:

```
​airports​[​"LHR"​] = ​"London"

dictionary["key"] = value
```

The below form would only work on an array, but an array would have a different form as they don't have keys: So it wouldn't really be used for anything.

```
dictionary += ["bear" : 1, "mouse" : 6]
```

page 172 in the swift programming guide on ibooks